# i want to create a customer bill type report using crystal reports in .net.HOw?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

i want to create a customer bill  type report using crystal reports in .net.
i know that a crystal report prints one header which conatins the colums headers and below the corresponding data colums from a table.But i want invoice type report in which i can keep
columns wherever i like in the report. e.g in the top left i want to keep- "To"-customer name
i want to create multiple headers and data rows. how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything in the Group Header section and suppress your Page Header section. Put a New Page After selection in your Group Footer (where your invoice total section will go). Then set your Group Header section to REPEAT on every page. So if you have a two page invoice, that header section will print twice.

And just to be clear, your Detail section will still contain your columns...

There are other ways, but this is probably the easiest way to explain concisely.